# How to sort string within struct alphabetically?

Tags: c++11

I am supposed to sort the employees' full name alphabetically. Basically, my question is how to sort string within struct alphabetically without using pointer.

here is a link to my code. I have completed most of the program, except the last piece - sorting string within struct alphabetically

https://repl.it/@Kailin_Z/qwe

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! For your question you need to create a [MCVE]/ Also don't post links to external code. All the relevant code must be included in the post. Please be aware that by far not all of the code in your external site is relevant to your isse so, once again, please create a [MCVE]. Also you need to show what you have tried and what doesn't work (with your specific issue, aka sorting). You will find that questions along the lines "how do I do X" without showing any attempt are not well received here.

Comment: I have an answer for you, but I won't post it until you [edit] the question to be up to what is required on this site (see my previous comment).

Comment: "sorting string within struct". This is probably not quite what you want. A string `"John Smith"` when sorted, within a struct or otherwise, will become `" JShhimnot".`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using algorithm::sort

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
struct Employee{
    std::string s;
    static bool comp(const Employee&e1, const Employee&e2){
        return e1.s.compare(e2.s)<0;
    }
};

int main(){
    Employee arr[] = {
        {"a"},
        {"c"},
        {"e"},
        {"b"},
        {"e"},
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), Employee::comp);
    for(const auto& e: arr){
        std::cout<<e.s<<std::endl;
    }
    //a
    //b
    //c
    //e
    //e
}
```

here is the [forked version link](https://repl.it/repls/TinyKeyInformation) (not sure it works)